# Sum the infinite series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How to solve this:

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\left[ \frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots \left( 2n-1\right) }{
2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots 2n}\right] ^{3}
\end{equation*}

I can make the bracket thing, $\left[ C(2n,n)/4^{n}\right] ^{3}$, but how to proceed now.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Let $\quad F(k)~=~\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty{2n\choose n}^k~x^n.\quad$ Then $\quad F(0)~=~\dfrac1{1-x}~,\quad F(1)~=~\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-4x}}~,\quad F(2)~=$ $=~\dfrac2\pi~K\big(4~\sqrt x\big)~,\quad$ and $\quad F(3)~=~\bigg[\dfrac2\pi~K\bigg(\dfrac{\sqrt{2-2~\sqrt{1-64x}}}2\bigg)\bigg]^2$.

Comment: Letting $~x=\bigg[\dfrac{\sin(2a)}{2^k}\bigg]^2,~$ with $~|a|<\dfrac\pi4,~$ the above expressions can be rewritten as $$F_0~=~\sec^2(2a),\quad F_1~=~\sec(2a),\quad F_2~=~\dfrac2\pi~K\Big(\sin(2a)\Big),\quad F_3~=~\bigg[\dfrac2\pi~K(\sin a)\bigg]^2.$$

Comment: See another proof via hypergeometric functions at http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2152231/72031

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We have:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\,x^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}},\tag{1} $$
$$\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(\sin x\right)^{2n}\,dx \tag{2}$$
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\right)^2 x^n = \frac{2}{\pi}\,K(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-x\sin^2\theta}}\tag{3} $$
hence by $(2)$ and $(3)$ it follows that:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\right)^3 &=& \frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}K(\sin^2 x)\,dx\\&=&\frac{4}{\pi^2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\varphi\sin^2\theta}}\,d\theta\,d\varphi\\&=&\frac{4}{\pi^2}\,K\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^4}},\tag{4}\end{eqnarray*}$$
so the original series equals $\displaystyle\color{purple}{-1+\frac{\pi}{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^4}=0.39320392968567685918424626\ldots}.$

<sup>Footnote: this is just a very special case of the identity $(6)$ for the square of the [complete elliptic integral of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html), plus the fact that $K(1/2)$ can be computed through the reflection and multiplication formulas for the $\Gamma$ function.</sup>

Comment: So the question is really hard and solution is tricky. Just one question @Jack D'Aurizio here the power term could be generalized (using 5 instead of 3) and solved in same way.

Comment: What an impressive looking solution!! Wallis would have been proud... :)

Comment: @MathsFun: yes, the generalization is just: $$\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\right)^{2k+1}=\phantom{}_{2k+1} F_{2k}\left(\frac{1}{2},\ldots,\frac{1}{2};1,\ldots,1;1\right).$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I just want to know how you combined (2) & (3) to get the main series. I mean how to multiply a expression with a power series ? It isn't the cauchy product

Comment: @AdityaNarayanSharma: expand $K(\sin^2\theta)$ in terms of $\sin\theta$ through $(3)$. Integrate termwise through $(2)$: there is no Cauchy product.

Comment: How did you express the double integral as a product of two integrals each with value $K(1/2)$?