# Proof of an Elliptic Integral Relation

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, pi, elliptic-integrals

In celebration of Pi Day, I messed around with the [following Ramanujan formula](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2011/03/14/a-ramanujan-series-for-calculating-pi/):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2 n}{n}^3 \frac{42 n+5}{2^{12 n+4}} = \frac1{\pi} $$

It turns out that, through some identities such as [the following](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2095780/a-ramanujan-infinite-series):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2 n}{n}^3 x^n = \frac{4 K\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{1-64 x}\right)\right)^2}{\pi ^2} $$

we can derive an analytical expression for the original sum.  This analytical expression leads me to the following question:

How does one prove the following relation?

> $$ 2 \sqrt{7} E(m) K(m) - (2+\sqrt{7}) K(m)^2 = \frac{\pi}{2} $$
>
> where
>
> $$K(m) = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{d \phi}{\sqrt{1-m \sin^2{\phi}}} $$
>   $$E(m) = \int_0^{\pi/2} d\phi \, \sqrt{1-m \sin^2{\phi}} $$
>
> and
>
> $$m = \frac{8-\sqrt{63}}{16} $$

It seems to me that there is some combination of the integrals that lends itself to a massive simplification, but I have yet to have found it.  Thus, I pose this to see if any of my fellow integral killers can drudge up any insights I may have missed.

Comment: Have you already exploited Legendre's relation? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_relation

Comment: Fortunately this is one of the three series for $1/\pi$ for which Ramanujan provided a proof. The method of Ramanujan is explained in my posts http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2012/03/modular-equations-and-approximations-to-pi-part-1.html and http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2012/03/modular-equations-and-approximations-to-pi-part-2.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gotcha: it is enough to exploit [Legendre's relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_relation) and the fact that
$$ m=\lambda^*(7)^2$$
with $\lambda^*$ being the [elliptic lambda function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticLambdaFunction.html).

Comment: Thank you for the tips.  It turns out that we also need the elliptic alpha function as well to complete the proof.  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticAlphaFunction.html

Comment: @RonGordon: you are clearly right (and there probably is no need to remark that :) ). I just went to the Wikipedia page related with some particular $K/K'$ ratios and figured out the exact details later, but they are simple to collect once we notice such peculiar identity. Wonderful times we live in, everyone can be Ramanujan for five minutes :D

Comment: I just love that I now understand the theory behind one of Ramanujan's insane sums.  It demonstrates just how ridiculously far ahead he was.